# FadeToggle change text and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a fade toggle to work. When you click on (+) two it is supposed to show two links and change to (-) two and when you press again it closes those links and goes back to (+) two. Right now, I can't get anything to happen when you press on the toggle.

```
<div id="ending">
  An everyday snapshot of
  <div class="toggle"><span style="font-size:11px">(+) </span>two </div> sfsfs



</div>

<div class="content">
  <a href="http://sfs.co.nz/" target="_blank">sfs</a> & <a href="http://sfsfs.co.nz/" target="_blank">sfsf</a>

</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? '(+) two' : '(-) two';
    $(".toggle").text(txt);
    $(".toggle").toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(450);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/b5tbfn5g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You actually have to reference/include the jQuery library for jQuery functions to work.

2) You had an improper selector.

- Rather than `$(this).next('.content').slideToggle(450);` 
  just use `$('.content').slideToggle(450);` or 
  `$(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle(450);`

The content div is *not* a sibling of the toggle div.. so next() isn't going to find it. But if you back up to the parent of the toggle div, then the content div *is* a sibling, so next() *will* find it.....

Depending on the rest of the markup, the selector *may* need to be further altered, but that's the main issue with the function overall.

Seems to work with the selector fixed and the jQuery library *actually* included.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".content").hide();
      $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? '(+) two' : '(-) two';
        $(".toggle").text(txt);
        $(".toggle").toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle(450);
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/b5tbfn5g/3/)